# How to prevent messy windows after error in emac-live

Tags: emacs, clojure, emacs24

I'm trying to get familiar with emacs and Clojure and its working out pretty well..
It's just that everytime I get a Clojure error, it will close any emacs-window except the one where the error occured and instead show me a giant empty window of "*popwin-dummy*".
I can't quite see how that's supposed to help me fixing any bug... Can you tell me how to disable this behaviour?
Have a nice day!

Comment: You should probably add some more details about your Emacs-Clojure integration setup.  I think Cider is the most popular package for this (and it's the one I use), but I don't want to assume that, since I've never gotten any behavior like this from my setup.

Comment: The setup I am using is just a clean emacs 24.5 with the emacs-live config (https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live).

Answer (score 1):

As a *general* protection against "Emacs messed up my window configuration" occurrences, add the following to your init file:

```
(winner-mode 1)
```

You can also toggle it for the current session with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `winner-mode`

Then whenever your window configuration is unexpectedly changed, use <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> to call `winner-undo` (which you can do repeatedly if necessary).

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><right></kbd> takes you back to the most recent configuration (immediately, rather than step-by-step).